# JavaScript change part of a TextNode string color with variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a webpage and have a text input as name, a color input, a textarea input as a comment and a checkbox. The goal is to make a comment section where a comment looks something like this:

> 2022/10/13-21:48:35 -- MyName: MyComment

Now my question is if there is any way to make only the MyName part of the comment the color from the color input.

So far my function looks like this (it's tied to a onclick "Submit" button).

```js
function newComment()
{
    var li = document.createElement('li');

    var commentsection = document.getElementById("commentsection");
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var color = document.getElementById("color");
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment");

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var hour = String(today.getHours()).padStart(2, '0');
    var min = String(today.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
    var sec = String(today.getSeconds()).padStart(2, '0');

    today = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd + '-' + hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(today + " -- " + name.value + ":    " + comment.value));

    var checkbox=document.getElementById("checkboxid");

    if(!checkbox.checked)
    {
        alert("You have to accept the TOS!");
        return;
    }

    if(name.value === '')
    {
        alert("Enter a name!");
        name.style.borderColor = 'red';
        return;
    }else if(comment.value === '')
    {
        alert("Write a comment!");
        comment.style.borderColor = 'red';
        return;
    }else
    {
        commentsection.appendChild(li);
    }

    name.style.borderColor = 'black';
    comment.style.borderColor = 'black';
    document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
}
```

I've tried numerous ways to change the color of name.value in the createTextNode but with no luck. If anyone has a working solution I would really be grateful!

Comment: You need to split it into multiple elements, so you can apply different CSS styles to them.

Comment: what is `document.getElementById("myInput")` tagName ? (it cann't be  INPUT)

Comment: @MisterJojo It's a textarea, if that is your question

Comment: edited the variable names so it's easier to understand

Comment: texts in textarea cannot be styled by words